# Cant access SDK manager on Android Studio 0.8.14

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I have downloaded Android Studio 0.8.14, I can't click (grey icon) on the SDK manager option in Configure menu. Also, it had no installation. it just opens when I click on studio64
EDIT: Thanks for the answers! It worked, I had to install the SDK separately and link it to android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have downloaded a .zip file of Android Studio from official site. Those zip files doesnt contain an embedded sdk install. I recommend downloading Android Studio Beta v0.8.14 from this link and install the setup. I also had the same problem and I installed the Android Studio Beta setup from the site and its working fine. Download [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must download the sdk.
Show under "GET THE SDK FOR AN EXISTING IDE"

[Downloadlink](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i#download)